# Get data from HTTP Request - Swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

Today I'm trying to get some data from a webpage.

It keeps crashing saying "Exc Bad Access", any suggestion ?

```
class CodeViewController: NSObject {

@IBOutlet var output_box : NSTextField
@IBOutlet var url_textField : NSTextField

var output : NSString = "Unable to load data"

func downloadHTML (path: String) -> String {
    var url = NSURL(string: "\(path)")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        self.output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
        //EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to set self.output new value
    }
    return output
}

@IBAction func retrive(sender: AnyObject!) {
     println(downloadHTML(url_textField.stringValue))
}

}
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on with EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: What is this "text" that you are returning? I can't see its declaration...

Comment: Forgot to change some var names for this question, edited..

Comment: Is there any reason why you are mixing NSString with the new String (Swift) data type?

Comment: Yeah, you are definately right. I will change everything

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "url_textField.stringValue" is nil at the point that you pass it in. Trying it with a fixed string works. But note also that the function will return before the async request completes, and so your code will always print "Unable to load". If you add a line that assigns the output to your output_box in the completion handler, you will see the the text box update once the request completes...

The code I tried, which works, is...

```
class CodeViewController: NSObject {

    var output : NSString = "Unable to load data"

    func downloadHTML (path: String) -> String {
        var url = NSURL(string: "\(path)")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        let completionBlock: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void = {response, data, error in
            self.output = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Asynch completed \(self.output)")
        }

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: completionBlock)

        return output
    }

}

var c: CodeViewController? = nil
c = CodeViewController()
c!.downloadHTML("http://www.google.com")
println("Immediate \(c!.output)")
```

and its output is:

Immediate Unable to load data
Asynch completed <!doctype html><html ...